# How to rank without skipping values?

Tags: stata

I need to rank rows by group (dates sorted by time in this case), but not skipping values where there are ties (similar to a Dense Rank in SQL), like this:

| Date | Time | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | 14:00 | 1 |
| 01/01/2021 | 15:00 | 2 |
| 01/01/2021 | 15:00 | 2 |
| 01/01/2021 | 16:00 | 3 |
| 01/01/2021 | 17:00 | 4 |
| 01/02/2021 | 14:00 | 1 |

I tried many combinations with rank() and _n, but I can't get to this result. How could this be done?

Comment: This is a duplicate, but the detailed code depends on exactly how your data are held in Stata.

Comment: Thanks Nick, the solution on that other post worked perfectly.